# No module named flaskext.mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972) Python-Flask Web App tutorial:

On Step 5, it says to install Flask-Mysql and then import it using this:

`from flaskext.mysql import MySQL`

However, I keep getting the error when I try to run the app that:

`ImportError: no module named flaskext.mysql`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I have MySQL installed already. I installed Flask and Flask-Mysql using `pip`.

Thank you,
Amy

Comment: You wrote `import flaskext.mysql from MySQL` but the tutorial says this: `from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL`

Comment: @idjaw I realized I typed the wrong form in my question. I used the tutorial's notation in my actual code. My question has been edited, sorry about this. Also, I tried `from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL` the first time, but the system returned the same error to me: `ImportError: no module named flask.ext.mysql`. I guess my version of Flask-MySQL was updated from what the author was using.

Answer (score 5):

first you have to install flask-mysql using following command:

sudo pip install flask-mysql

and then import mysql 
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
it works fine for me :)